GoLang mocking methods
I have a simple service:
package services

type X struct {
    Name string
}

func (x X) Valid() bool {
    return x.Name != ""
}

type Service struct{}

func (service Service) Do(x X) bool {
    return x.Valid()
}

And a test file that goes with it:
package services_test

import (
    "playground/services"
    "testing"
)

func TestService_valid(t *testing.T) {
    x := services.X{
        Name: "something",
    }
    service := services.Service{}

    did := service.Do(x)

    if !did {
        t.Fatalf("it didn't do the thing, but should")
    }
}

func TestService_invalid(t *testing.T) {
    x := services.X{}
    service := services.Service{}

    did := service.Do(x)

    if did {
        t.Fatalf("it did do the thing, but shouldn't")
    }
}

I'm currently setting my X to be valid or invalid based on the knowledge of what the Valid() function actually checks for, in the future when the validity of my X is no longer just related to the Name property I would have to update all my tests.
I'd much rather just mock out the Valid method directly and have it return what I want to happen in the specific test. However, all my attempts either overcomplicate the business logic (which I don't want to change necessarily) or require me to pass an interface to my Do function. I don't feel like wrapping every parameter of my service methods in interfaces just so i can mock them in my tests.
I'm probably approaching this whole problem from the wrong angle, but I can't seem to find a clean way of doing this.
The thing I want to accomplish in my test is something like this
type mockX struct {
    IsValid bool
}

func (m mockX) Valid() bool {
    return m.IsValid
}

func TestService_valid(t *testing.T) {
    mock := mockX{IsValid: true}
    service := services.Service{}
    did := service.Do(mock)

    if !did {
        t.Fatalf("it didn't do the thing, but should")
    }
}

func TestService_invalid(t *testing.T) {
    mock := mockX{IsValid: false}
    service := services.Service{}
    did := service.Do(mock)

    if did {
        t.Fatalf("it did do the thing, but shouldn't")
    }
}

But the typechecker doesn't like me passing in an xMock where an X is expected (which is logical)

Pass an interface instead of a struct to the Do function :
type XInterface {
    Valid() bool
}

func (service Service) Do(x XInterface) bool {
    return x.Valid()
}

Edit: Or add a supplementary abstraction layer in the service:
type ValidatorInterface interface {
    Validate(x X) bool
}

type Service struct{
    Validator ValidatorInterface
}

func (service Service) Do(x X) bool {
    return service.Validator.Validate(x)
}

And use it in your tests:
type mockValidator struct {
    isValid bool
}

func (m mockValidator) Validate(x X) bool {
    return m.isValid
}

service := services.Service{
    Validator: mockValidator{
         isValid: true,
    }
}

did := service.Do(X)


I understand that this is probably the best way to go. but something feels weird to me when i'm wrapping every parameter to my services in a wrapper, while in practice there won't ever be any implementation for the XInterface other than X itself (and mockX). I feel like i'm overcomplicating the business logic, just to facilitate testing

I see what you mean, I have updated my response to add another option, more verbose though.

i've been circling around these options as well, but i still feel like that's changing a lot of business code just for testing. This last version would also require the initialiser of the service to know how the validation is supposed to happen, which should be a model responsibility. Secondly if my service would require multiple models to operate, i'd have to pass in a validator for each model just so i could mock it in my tests. This would get messy really quickly.
I feel like i'm shoving a square peg in a round hole, and i'm just fighting the typechecker or lack of a mocking framework
